# Unwanted horizontal scrollbar, when rep hits 10k+ (plus badges)

Tags: bug, design, user-interface, top-bar, responsive-design

I am facing a little CSS annoyance with the top bar containing my rep count representation:

[image: screenshot of profile page]

Can we get rid of that horizontal scrollbar please. If necessary shorten the rep/badge info from the profile flavor.

It seems that the top bar div requires a horizontal scrollbar up to a specific rep representation.
I'd prefer the shortened rep representation by means of 84k rep.

Comment: Probably rep + badges.

Comment: huh... i only get that in mobile. I can't recreate it with desktop, though i do have 2 of those 5 icons + "Products" hidden. *weird*

Comment: See [The top bar's Stack Exchange logo is permanently max-width and squeezes out the site switcher on mobile, requiring scrolling to access](/q/377585/289905) and [Topbar on mobile clogged: here’re some suggestions](/q/377593/289905).

Comment: @KevinB yes that's with mobile view (my android tablet + chrome), didn't test with desktop yet.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ mobile view is desktop view, for what it's worth. Desktop just never gets narrow enough, for me, to introduce the scrollbar

Comment: I only see it on desktop if I shrink the Window width drastically.

Comment: You need a bigger screen ... CGA is so '90 ...

Comment: How often do you need those last two icons or the "products" ad anyway? Block them off with UBlock origin and you're done.

Comment: (Firefox does support extensions on mobile)

Comment: @AyxanHaqverdili I use the siteswitcher (last icon) dozens of times a day.

Comment: FYI, I was watching [this youtube vid](https://youtu.be/IbDAmvUwo5c?t=401) and you're featured.